# How can I access class methods from a different file in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I've got a simple class `MyApp` in a `main.dart` file, with two functions in it (`setLocale`, `setThemeMode`).

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();

  static State<MyApp> of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.findAncestorStateOfType<_MyAppState>()!;
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {

    void setLocale(String language) {}
    void setThemeMode(ThemeMode mode) {}

}
```

And I would like to use them within functions in different file `flutter_flow.dart` (no class, clean file with these functions).

```
void setAppLanguage(BuildContext context, String language) =>
    MyApp.of(context).setLocale(language);

void setDarkModeSetting(BuildContext context, ThemeMode themeMode) =>
    MyApp.of(context).setThemeMode(themeMode);
```

And I'm stuck with this error.
`The method 'setLocale' isn't defined for the type 'State'. Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'setLocale'.`

As far as I understand, file does not see this methods although I'm importing file with class MyApp. May I ask for help, what to do, where to search for solution?

Comment: you can't call any function that resides in your main from another file. what you can do is declare the functions you put in your main else where in a different file and call it where ever you need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the return type of

```dart
State<MyApp> of(BuildContext context)
```

to

```dart
_MyAppState of(BuildContext context)
```

---

With your current code, when you do

```dart
MyApp.of(context)
```

it returns the type `State<MyApp>` which is the generic `State` class [from flutter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) which won't contain any of your custom methods.

When you change the return of `of(BuildContext context)` to `_MyAppState`, `MyApp.of(context)` will return `_MyAppState` type. The dart analyzer knows that it has your custom methods `setLocale` and `setThemeMode` and won't throw an error anymore.